# Force API Controller implementation

Tags: c#, rest, api, owin

I would like to have an implementation for a specific API controller, that will be implemented with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin, for creating a rest api with .net core.

I would like to give others the option for implementing their own, similar controllers, but also have some restrictions to what they have to implement. For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("calculator")]
public class CalculatorController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("add/{int1}/{int2}")]
    public int AddItems(int int1, int int2)
    {
        return int1 + int2;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("multiply/{int1}/{int2}")]
    public int MultiplyItems(int int1, int int2)
    {
        return int1 * int2;
    }
}
```

I suppose I can create an interface (e.g. `ICanCalculate`) that will have the two methods `AddItems` and `MultiplyItems`, but is there a way to force the `Route` and `HttpMethod` attributes?

Basically I want to give other users the option to alter the body of the api endpoint without changing the `Route` or the `HttpMethod` attributes.

Maybe an alternative would be to create some `abstract class` that will have the methods as `virtual`? I'm not quite sure how to approach the problem and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not possible inherit from your controller to keep the attributes and change only the body directly (at least not in a clean way).

The best option is addding an intermediate layer (abstract class) and use it in your controller. Than other users can implement the abstract class (not the controller directly) with their own logic.